# error during catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin-make, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm completely new to ROS (and Ubuntu) and I'm having some trouble when trying to use the command catkin_make (I'm following the tutorial to configure ROS environment).

The error message is the following:

```
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "std/-msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    std/-msgsConfig.cmake
    std/-msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "std/-msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "std/-msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "std/-msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

I'm not sure, but I think I did something wrong when I created the beginner_tutorials package in another tutorial. Maybe I mistyped the name of the package **std_msgs** in the dependencies field? Anyway, even if this is the case, I don't know how to proceed to fix it.

How should I proceed to fix this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183212/error-during-catkin_make/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-04**:
Please post your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that in your CMakeLists.txt you say something like

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std/-msgs )
```

rather than

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std_msgs )
```

Note: std_msgs is the correct package name

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-04**:
thank you Wolf! It worked!

**Comment by [Ringo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25901/ringo/) on 2016-02-10**:
Thanks. It helps.

**Comment by [cemal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32072/cemal/) on 2017-09-28**:
I dont have something like find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std/-msgs ) this text in my  CMakeLists.txt .How can i fix it?